# Invoke a lambda from VSCode python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lambda, invoke

could not find any answer on this.

All the tutorials mention how to use AWS toolkit or how to locally develop and test your lambda on VSCode. That's not what I would like, I already have a lambda, and I would just like to invoke it.

To call a s3 or Dynamo DB, I can just run

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
scan_kwargs = {
    'FilterExpression': Key(my_key).eq(key_equal)
}
response = table.scan(**scan_kwargs)
data = response['Items']
```

What is the equivalent for invoking the lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='')

lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='', InvocationType='', Payload='')
```

Where the empty strings can be replaced with your information.

See: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#client